# Exit time for Brownian motion with stochastic barriers

Tags: pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, brownian-motion

I am interested in the expected exit time of a one-dimensional Brownian particle from a stochastically evolving interval as follows.

**Context:**

If $L_t$ and $R_t$ denote the distance to the left and right boundaries at time $t$ respectively, then the process $(L,R)$ has generator
\begin{multline}
Af(l,r) = \frac{1}{2} ( \partial^2_{ll} - 2 \partial^2_{lr} + \partial^2_{rr})f(l,r) + \lambda \bigg\{ \int_0^l (f(u,r)-f(l,r))du + \int_0^\infty (f(l+s,r)-f(l,r))e^{-s} ds \bigg\} \\
 + \lambda \bigg\{ \int_0^r (f(l,u)-f(l,r))du + \int_0^\infty (f(l,r+s)-f(l,r))e^{-s} ds \bigg\}.
\end{multline}
for some $\lambda > 0$. This process has the following interpretation. If $(L_0,R_0) = (l,r)$, then

- a particle, initially at the origin, diffuses until it first exits $(-l,r)$; instead here we are evolving the boundaries and waiting until the first time either $L_t=0$ or $R_t = 0$;
- the boundaries are allowed to jump:

  - at rate $\lambda l$, the process $L$ jumps to a uniformly chosen point in $(0,l)$;
  - at rate $\lambda$, the process $L$ jumps to $l + E$, with $E \sim \mathtt{Exponential}(1)$ (independent of everything else);
  - similarly for the right boundary $R$.

It is straightforward to check that $\phi(l,r) = e^{-(l+r)}$ is a stationary density for the process, ie if $L_0$ and $R_0$ are independent exponential random variables with unit mean, then so are $L_t$ and $R_t$ for all $t$. That is,
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty Af(l,r) e^{-(l+r)} dl dr = 0.
\end{equation}

**Aim:**

I wish to compute
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}_\phi \tau = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \mathbf{E}[\tau \, |\, L_0 = l, R_0 = r] e^{-l} e^{-r} dl dr,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\tau = \inf\{t\geq0: L_t R_t = 0\},
\end{equation}
that is, the expected time to hit either $L_t = 0$ or $R_t =0$ starting from the stationary distribution.

**Thoughts thus far:**

In the case that $\lambda = 0$, then the problem reduces to the mean first exit time of $(-l,r)$ of a one-dimensional Brownian motion. It is well known that this is given by $lr$.

Although in this setting the boundaries are jumping, since we start from the stationary (exponential distribution), then on average the boundary is a distance 1 to the left and a distance 1 to the right, leading us to guess that $\mathbf{E}_\phi \tau = 1$.

A standard, maybe naive, approach would be to find a solution $g$ the boundary value problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
Ag(l,r)=-1, & \text{for all } (l,r) \in (0,\infty)^2, \\
g(0,r) = g(l,0) = 0, & l,r\in[0,\infty);
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
given which,
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}_\phi \tau = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty g(l,r) e^{-(l+r)} dl dr.
\end{equation}
However, it is not easy to identify a solution. Taking cues from the classical case, with $\lambda = 0$, it is straightforward to compute that with
\begin{align}
&h(l,r) = lr,\\
&Ah(l,r) = -1 + \lambda \big\{ -\frac{1}{2} l^2 r + r - \frac{1}{2} l r^2 + l \big\},
\end{align}
so that
\begin{equation}
L_t R_t -L_0R_0 + t - \lambda \int_0^t \big\{ -\frac{1}{2} L_s^2 R_s + R_s - \frac{1}{2} L_s R_s^2 + L_s \big\} ds
\end{equation}
is a martingale. Taking $t = \tau$ and taking expectations with respect to $\mathbf{E}_\phi$, a naive application of Dynkin's formula or the optional stopping theorem would then 'yield'
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}_\phi \tau = 1 + \lambda \mathbf{E}_\phi \bigg[ \int_0^\tau \big\{ -\frac{1}{2} L_s^2 R_s + R_s - \frac{1}{2} L_s R_s^2 + L_s \big\} ds \bigg].
\end{equation}

**Specific questions:**

- Given stationarity, can I conclude that the expectation on the right hand side here is 0? This isn't trivial because I am integrating up to the stopping time, but very naively passing the expectation under the integral would give zero, as hoped.
- Broadly, is attempting to solve to the boundary value problem the right approach? What other methods may I try?
- My approach has been to decompose $A = A_1 + A_2$, where $A_1$ corresponds to diffusion of the boundaries and $A_2$ corresponds to jumping; I have solved the boundary value problem for $A_1$. Is there something like a Feynman--Kac correction which would then give me the solution for the whole problem? My PDE knowledge is limited so I would be grateful of even general pointers here.